# combobox find record based on two fields

Tags: ms-access, combobox, macros

I have a combo box in a form to find a specific record;

The combo box data source is a query that has 2 fields: OB and OC ;

So far I have managed to find the record based on field OB;

But now a need to find the record using 2 criteria’s: Field OB and Field OC

Any help so I can include field OC and find the record based on two fields?

```
Condition where ="[OB] = " & "'" & [Screen].[ActiveControl] & "'"
```

Comment: You should add the correct tags to your question ([edit]). Otherwise nobody reads your question because nobody finds it. E.g. if this is about MS Access then add the `ms-access` tag. Please take a [tour] and read [ask] to improve your question.

Comment: thanks for the advise

Comment: Reference combobox columns by index. Index begins with 0 so if value is in column 2, the index is 1. `Me.comboboxname.Column(1)`. Combobox items don't have a unique ID can use as criteria?

Comment: I did not have a unique identifier in my table/query. I created one, included it in my combo box (column 0; 0 cm) and my macro now pulls the record based on this unique identifier. It works great Thanks a lot!!